# Convert float column to int based on column list Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

What is the quickest way of converting column data types in pandas based on a list of columns below. I only want to convert the specified list to integers from floats. The list is dynamic, used within a function, so I need it do be based on a generated list

I have the code below but I want to simplify it

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a' : [1.0,2.0,3.0],
    'b' : [4.0,5.0,6.0],
    'c' : [7.0,8.0,9.0]})

df

    a   b   c
0   1.0 4.0 7.0
1   2.0 5.0 8.0
2   3.0 6.0 9.0

test_df.dtypes

a    float64
b    float64
c    float64

col_list = ['a', 'b']

col_dtype_zip = zip(col_list, ['int32']*len(col_list))

col_dtype_dict = {key:value for (key,value) in col_dtype_zip}

test_df = test_df.astype(col_dtype_dict)

test_df.dtypes

dtype: object
a      int32
b      int32
c    float64
```

Comment: `df[col_list]=df[col_list].astype(int)` ?

Comment: `df[col_list]=df[col_list].astype('int32')`

Comment: My columns have none values, so it's not working however, but the above answer my q